# Number of marked cells

Tags: graph-theory

Given is a n × n grid whose cells are partially marked. The grid is represented by a
n × n matrix whose entries are zero unless the cell (i, j) is marked. In this case, the entry
M[i, j] = 1.
A monotonic path through the grid starts in the upper left cell and ends in the lower
right cell of the grid. The path may move in one step only to the cell to the right or
down. Diagonal steps are not allowed. The goal of the optimization is to determine a
minimum set P of monotone paths that cover all marked cells. We call a cell z covered if
a path P ∈ P passes over the marked cell z.

I need to describe an algorithm to compute a monotone path that covers the maximum
number of marked cells. Justify the correctness and efficiency of the algorithm.

Also: A simple greedy heuristic for determining a minimum set of monotone paths that
cover the marked cells is as follows:
If there are still marked cells in the grid, determine a monotone path that covers a
maximum number of marked cells. Unmark the cells and repeat this procedure until
no more marked cells exist. Show that this algorithm does not always determine[image]
the optimal solution

if anyone can explain how to do this task, I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: For the first question, try a dynamic programming approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"determine A monotone path that covers the maximum number of marked cells" How to choose if there are several? Consider $\begin{bmatrix}&&*\\*&&*\\*&&\end{bmatrix}$ and recognize that the path Down,Right,Right,Down satisfies the requirement of being a path that maximized number of marked cells it hits, but we will still have two more paths yet to go, having covered two in the first path, one in second, and one in third... rather than having done the more efficient thing of going down,down,right,right for the first path and then right,right,down,down for the second getting all marked squares in just two

As for a better and clearer approach, my first instinct is to hit those in the bottom left as best I can... I'm struggling to phrase correctly and precisely, but the punchline is to take as many points $(a,b)$ who satisfy that no other point $(c,d)$ is still marked such that $c<a$ and $d<b$...  Another attempt of wording this is, look at current column and where our current position is.  If any marked squares still exist in this column lower than current position then take the path to the bottom such marked square.  Once no other marked squares exist in this column, shift right one and repeat.

Pardon the poor paint skills, but this should get the idea across

[image]